# laravel eloquent hasmany or hasmany trough

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, eloquent

I have structure like this

```
table events with column id  
table users with column id 
table topics with columns id, event_id, user_id
```

what I want is to get API with

```
events{
  id, 
  topics{all topics here}, // this part is working
  users{users relevant to single topic here} // not sure how to do this
}
```

my Controller looks like this

```
class EventsController extends Controller
{
    public function index(Request $request)
    {
        $events = Event::with('topics', 'users')->get();
        $response = ['events' => $events];
        return response($response, 200);
    }...
```

and my model is this

```
class Event extends Model
{
    protected $table = 'events';
    //

    public function topics()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Topic::class, 'event_id');
    }

    public function users()
    {
       return $this->hasMany(User::class, 'id');
    }
}
```

but this function users from the model is returning only users which event.id is in displaying so if event id is 2 I will get only user with id 2

can I somehow write custom query inside Model? or return all relevant users? or simply return all users, but inside that event response?

Comment: You should use a [`BelongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

Comment: A user has many events and a event has many users. In your User-model: `$this->belongsToMany(Event::class, 'topics');` In your Event-model: `$this->belongsToMany(User::class);`. You should pass the table name `topics` because your not keeping to Laravels convention, which would be `event_user`. This is called a Many to Many-relationship